# How to get javascript object properties to php variables with ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a javascript object containing some values inside that. I'm using jquery-ajax to send it to php.
In php file how to get that javascript object properties and store it into the php variable

Here is my code (javascript object and ajax call)

```
    var script = document.createElement("SCRIPT");
    script.src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
    crossorigin="anonymous";
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);


   var person = { userID: "", name: "", accessToken: "", picture: "", email: ""};

        function logIn() {
            FB.login(function (response) {
                if (response.status == "connected") {
                    person.userID = response.authResponse.userID;
                    person.accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;

                    FB.api('/me?fields=id,name,email,picture.type(large)', function (userData) {
                        person.name = userData.name;
                        person.email = userData.email;
                        person.picture = userData.picture.data.url;
                        // ajax code start
                        $.ajax({
                           url: "insert.php",
                           method: "POST",
                           data: person,
                           dataType: 'text',
                           success: function (serverResponse) {

                               if (true)
                                   window.location = "index.php";
                           }
                        });
                        // ajax code end
                    });
                }
            }, {scope: 'public_profile, email'})
        }

        function logout(){
           FB.getLoginStatus( function(response){
              if(response.status == 'connected'){
                  FB.logout( function(response){
                      $.ajax({
                          url : 'logout.php',
                          success : function(data){
                              if(true){
                                  window.location = 'login.php';
                              }
                          }
                      });
                  });
              };
           });
        }

        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
                appId            : '',
                autoLogAppEvents : true,
                xfbml            : true,
                version          : 'v2.11'
            });
        };

        (function(d, s, id){
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Where person object stores after button click, and that data will be coming from Facebook api call..

And in insert.php (i tires like this)

```
<?php 

  require_once 'dbconfig.php';

    if($_POST){
        $userID = $_POST['userID'];
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $picture = $_POST['name'];
        $access_token = $_POST['access_token'];
    }



    $stmt = $db_con->prepare('INSERT INTO users(userID,uname,email,picture,access_token) VALUES(:uid, :uname, :email ,:picture, :access_token)');
    $stmt->bindParam(':uid',$userID);
    $stmt->bindParam(':uname',$name);
    $stmt->bindParam(':email',$email);
    $stmt->bindParam(':picture',$picture);
    $stmt->bindParam(':access_token',$access_token);
    $stmt->execute();    
   }
?>
```

After action performed, it wil successfully redirected to index.php but , values not stored in database.
What might be the cause..
thanks in advance

Comment: `var person = { userID: "", name: "", accessToken: "", picture: "", email: ""};` all values are empty.

Comment: Can you share the values from  `var person = { userID: "", name: "", accessToken: "", picture: "", email: ""};`

Comment: i updated my question..can you please look at once

Comment: you could also enclose your db insertion codes inside a `try...catch` block to see other possible issues.